# Python - 'if not'

Tags: python

The following codes

```
multiples = []
for i in range(1,1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        multiples.append(i)
addition = sum(multiples)
print addition
```

and

```
print(sum([i for i in range(1, 1000) if not (i%3 and i%5)]))
```

do the same thing.

Now how does the `if not` part compute in the second code?

What I'm saying is, in the first code the `i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0` had to be exclusively stated whereas the same thing is achieved on the second code without the `== 0`.

Comment: First off, they do not do the same thing... the former does a whole lot of redundant calls to sum.  They do however, output the same thing.  In python and in many languages, zero is considered to be False and non-zero is True.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Oh, the frequent calls to sum was a mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

Using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0
```

is the same as:

```
not (i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0)
```

And in python, when converting a number to a boolean, any non-zero value becomes `True`.

So instead of doing `i % 3 != 0` in the `if`, you can just use `i % 3`, because if it's `0` it'll be `False` and if it's non-zero it'll be `True`.

Here's python's truth table: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#truth

P.S. `sum()` can take a generator as an argument, so you can actually just do:

```
sum(i for i in range(1, 1000) if not (i%3 and i%5))
```

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` are boolean operators, not logical `&` and `|`. So writing

```
a == 0 or b == 0
```

is the same as writing

```
not a or not b
```

So they do the same thing

As a conclusion, the best way is to avoid negations in your conditions, don't create extra list comprehension but use generator comprehension instead, and I wouldn't mind testing against zero instead of using `not` since they're integers after all. I would do this:

```
print(sum(i for i in range(1, 1000) if i%3==0 or i%5==0))
```

Comment: I promise I typed it wrong. In the original code the sum was done out of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is an effect of the way Python converts integers to booleans. The result of `i % 3` is 0, 1, or 2, depending on the value of `i`. In Python 3.x (and by default also in Python 2.x, unless you've reassigned them) all non-zero integers evaluate to `False` and zero evaluates to `True`.

Thus `if not (i % 3)` will evaluate `(i % 3)` to an integer 0, 1, or 2, and then `not` will convert these to `False`, `True`, `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python `0` is usual interpreted as false. So in the first code block `i % 3 == 0` is effectively equivalent to `not i % 3`. Examples from command line:

```
>>> 6 % 3 == 0
True
>>> not 6 % 3
True
>>> 7 % 3 == 0
False
>>> not 7 % 3
False
```

This shortcut of `0 === false` appears in many languages and can be a bit confusing if you're not used to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Python every object has a boolean value.

In the case of integers any of them is `True` except `0`.

So in your case when number `i` can be divided by `3` the expression `i % 3` will be `0`. But we know that `0` is `False`. The `not` operator will negate this expression so `not False` will become `True`.

The same holds for `not i % 5` as well.

Hope it helps.

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. [1]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

See also:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

see, i % 3 == 0 return true if the condition satisfy. Now, in python suppose:

```
 i = 6
 6 % 3 = 0 and 0==0 is true
```

There fore the result will be true.
In the second case

```
6 % 3 = 0.
```

Now, in boolean 0 means false. So by using not it means not false, i.e, true.